# labels are not displayed vertically and the values of gc.weightx and gc.weighty are not working

Tags: java, user-interface

##This is SubPaneli class.

When i place only two labels,the labels are displayed vertically which i want but as i place third label it goes vertically and on the top of that weightx and weighty is not working i have attached image of the result of the code.I am useing gridbag layout.Am i using it wrong or what?I want some help

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.Border;

    class SubPanelI extends JPanel {
        JLabel Title,Ylabel,Xlabel,Xstart,Xinterval;
        JTextField Ylabelf,Xlabelf,Xstartf,Xintervalf;

        public SubPanelI()
        {

        Dimension dim = getPreferredSize();
        dim.width=400;
        setPreferredSize(dim);
        Border innerBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("LABEL");
        Border outerBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outerBorder,innerBorder));
    //  Title= new JLabel("Tile:");

        Ylabel = new JLabel("YLabel: ");
        Ylabelf = new JTextField(10);

        Xlabel= new JLabel("XLabel: ");
        Xlabelf = new JTextField(10);

        Xinterval = new JLabel("XInterval: ");
        Xintervalf = new JTextField(10);



        setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 
        GridBagConstraints gc =  new GridBagConstraints();


        /////////////////first row/////////////////////////////

        gc.weightx=1;
        gc.weighty=0.1;
        gc.gridx=0;
        gc.gridy=0;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gc.anchor =GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        add(Ylabel, gc);


        gc.gridx =1;
        gc.gridy =0;

        gc.anchor =GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        add(Ylabelf, gc);

        ////////////////Second row/////////////////////////
        gc.weightx=1;
        gc.weighty=0.1;                                                                                  ;
        gc.gridx =0;
        gc.gridy =1;
        gc.anchor =GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        add(Xlabel, gc);

        gc.gridx =1;
        gc.gridy =1;
        gc.anchor =GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        add(Xlabelf, gc);

        ///////////////third row///////////////////////
        gc.weightx=1;
        gc.weighty=1.0;
        gc.gridx =2;
        gc.gridy =1;
        gc.anchor =GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        add(Xinterval);

        gc.gridx =1;
        gc.gridy =2;
        gc.anchor =GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        add(Xintervalf);




        }
    }
```

[image]#

Comment: For the first row you set `gc.gridy = 0` and `gc.gridx = 0` / `gc.gridx = 1`. For the second row you set `gc.gridy = 1` and gc.gridx the same as in the first row. However for the third row you set `gc.gridx = 2; gc.gridy = 1;` / `gc.gridx = 1; gc.gridy = 2;`. This looks wrong

Comment: what should i do then?

Comment: For the thrid row they should be `gc.gridx = 0; gc.gridy = 2;`  and `gc.gridx = 1; gc.gridy = 2;`

Comment: did not work yar

Comment: Upon further examination of your code: when adding `Xinterval` and `Xintervalf` you are missing the `gc` parameter, meaning the layout engine has no information where you want to place these components.

Comment: Thank you veryyyyyyyyyyyyy much